# Как включить анимацию в onDraw

Tags: android

```
public class Myture extends View{
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    ImageView bitmap=new ImageView(getContext());
    bitmap.setImageResource(R.drawable.ani);
    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable= (AnimationDrawable) bitmap.getDrawable();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, posX, posY, null);
animationDrawable.start();
}
}
```

Не пойму как можно добавить в onDraw Bitmap в canvas и одновременно включить анимацию AnimationDrawable. Что не так то с моим кодом?

Comment: Нужна помощь, пожалуйста помогите

Answer (score 3):

Прежде, чем "включать анимацию в onDraw", подумайте, действительно ли вам нужно это. Расскажите лучше, какую задачу вы пытаетесь таким способом решить.

В `onDraw()` выполнять указанные вами действия категорически нельзя. Во время анимации onDraw может быть вызван с десяток, а то и сотню раз.
В `onDraw` у вас должно быть все уже готово, чтобы только нарисовать bitmap на предоставленном canvas'е.

Посмотрите пример в [документации на AnimationDrawable.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) Там все действия можно производить в активности. Не нужно переопределять View, достаточно стандартного ImageView (и даже обычного View). `animationDrawable.start()` вызывается там, где удобнее. Можно, например, вызвать его в `onResume()`, или в обработчике нажатия какой-нибудь кнопки.

Comment: Поддерживаю. onDraw не место для вызова анимации.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin, подскажите тогда, когда лучше вызывать анимацию, если работаешь с канвасом и SurfaceView?